# Why "despite" and "yet" can't be used at the same time?

Tags: conditionals

This problem came from a poster on F*cebook (credit to the owner).

> **Despite the fact that** the roads are icy, I ___ staying home, **yet** I ___
> going shopping.
>
> **a) am**
>
> **b) am not**

Maybe i could agree if the sentence is grammatically incorrect since there's a conflict between "Despite the fact that" and "yet".

I don't understand how it works, sometimes in some cases we're allowed to use double meaning or contrast (e.g. double negatives) in order to say the same in another way or just emphasize the sentence just like the same topic that I had asked yesterday.

So, in my case, is this sentence correct? If it isn't, please explain :

> ***Despite the fact that the roads are icy, I'm not staying home, yet I'm going shopping.***

Comment: The problem with that sentence isn't that it has both "despite" and "yet." The problem with that sentence is that it is incoherent. If the sentence instead read, "Despite the fact that the roads aren't icy, I'm staying home, yet I'm going shopping," it'd be perfectly fine because it'd be coherent, illustrating that "despite" and "yet" appearing in the same sentence isn't the problem.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Thanks for the reply. Is it "yet I'm going shopping" or "yet I'm not going shopping"? If the first one, so it has a negation?

Comment: "Yet" when used as a coordinating conjunction, like it is there, is used to introduce information that thematically contrasts or contradicts, either actually or seemingly, the information presented in the preceding clause. In my example, I used "yet" to introduce my "going shopping," which is seemingly contrasting or contradicting my "staying home" and thus not going anywhere in the preceding clause, a seeming contrast or contradiction that I might later resolve by explaining that I'm not going shopping at brick-and-mortar stores but am going shopping online, which I can do while staying home.

Comment: Please stop using Facebook to learn grammar. That's like hoping to find a 5-star meal in the sewer. You might get lucky, but you'll get sick first.